# string convert to datetime timezone

Tags: python, datetime

I want to linear interpolation some points between two time string.

So I try to convert string to datetime then insert some point then convert datetime to string. but it seems the timezone not correct.

In below example. I wish to insert one point between 9-28 11:07:57.435" and "9-28 12:00:00.773".

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
from time import mktime
from datetime import datetime

#-----------------------------------------#
def main():
    dtstr = [
"9-28 11:07:57.435",
"9-28 12:00:00.773"
]
    print "input",dtstr
    dtlst = str2dt(dtstr)
    floatlst = dt2float(dtlst)

    bins = 3
    x1 = list(np.arange(floatlst[0],floatlst[-1],(floatlst[-1]-floatlst[0])/bins))
    dtlst = float2dt(x1)
    dtstr = dt2str(dtlst)
    print "output",dtstr
    return

def str2dt(strlst):
    dtlst = [datetime.strptime("2014-"+i, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") for i in strlst]
    return dtlst

def dt2float(dtlst):
    floatlst = [mktime(dt.timetuple()) for dt in dtlst]
    return floatlst

def dt2str(dtlst):
    dtstr = [dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z") for dt in dtlst]
    return dtstr

def float2dt(floatlst):
    dtlst = [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds) for seconds in floatlst]
    return dtlst

#-----------------------------------------#
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output looks like:

```
input ['9-28 11:07:57.435', '9-28 12:00:00.773']
output ['2014-09-28 16:07:57 ', '2014-09-28 16:25:18 ', '2014-09-28 16:42:39 ']
```

Two questions here:

1. The input and output has 4 hours differ (9-28 16:07:57 to 9-28 11:07:57). I guess it caused by timezone but not sure how to fix it.
2. I wish the first and last point the same as input, but now it seems the last point is less than the input last point (16:42:39 vs 12:00:00).

Comment: You may be interested in **[pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net)** library

Comment: And what do you mean by inserting some points, like **timedelta**?

Comment: @Anzel yes,I just want to generate a interpolation result just like add a timedelta.it seems arange and linspace both not support datetime object.

Comment: read about [difficulties that you might encounter when doing date arithmetics with local time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279)

Comment: unrelated: A cleaner design would define functions that operate on a scalar. If you need to apply it to a list; you could always use `map()`: `timestamps = map(local2posix, dtlst)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. You're right about the timezones, you're using `time.mktime` which [converts struct_time to seconds assuming the input is local time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime), but then using [`datetime.utcfromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) which (naturally) converts to utc.  Use [`datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) instead to keep everything in local time.

Q2. As with the native Python `range`/`xrange`, when you do `numpy.arange(x, y, z)`, the result starts with x and goes upto, but not including y *([except in weird floating point roundoff cases.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011302/python-numpy-arange-unexpected-results)  Don't rely on this behaviour)*.  if you want consistent behaviour on the end points w/ floating values, use [numpy.linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)

On the other hand, why convert datetime to seconds, then go back again?  datetime objects support addition and subtraction.  Below would be my suggestion.

```
from time import mktime, localtime
from datetime import datetime
from copy import copy

def main():
    input_timestrings = ["9-28 11:07:57.435", "9-28 12:00:00.773"]
    input_datetimes = timestrings_to_datestimes(input_timestrings)

    start_datetime = input_datetimes[0]
    end_datetime = input_datetimes[1]

    # subtraction between datetime objects returns a timedelta object
    period_length = end_datetime - start_datetime

    bins = 3

    # operation w/ timedelta objects and datetime objects work pretty much as you'd expect it to
    delta = period_length / bins
    datetimes = list(custom_range(start_datetime, end_datetime + delta, delta))
    output_timestrings = datetimes_to_timestrings(datetimes)

    print output_timestrings
    return

def timestrings_to_datetimes(timestrings):
    datetimes = [datetime.strptime("2014-"+timestring, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") for timestring in timestrings]
    return datetimes

def datetimes_to_timestrings(datetimes):
    timestrings = [datetime_.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z") for datetime_ in datetimes]
    return timestrings

def custom_range(start, end, jump):
    x = start
    while x < end:
        yield x
        x = x + jump


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. so linspace doesn't support datetime object, so you create a cunstom_range function. good idea.

Comment: If `input_datetimes` are naive datetime objects that represent local time then `end_datetime - start_datetime` might be wrong in some cases. [local time may be not linear or monotonous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892763/string-convert-to-datetime-timezone#comment44193886_27892763)

Comment: Thanks, duly noted.  'Do everything in UTC' is critical advice.