# Plotted arc: anomaly in the plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def arc():
    x = np.arange((-np.pi)/4, (np.pi)/4, 0.001)

    f1 = lambda x: 3 * (np.cos(2 * x) )**0.5
    plt.vlines(0, 0, 5)
    plt.plot(x, f1(x), label = '$r=3\sqrt{\cos{2\phi}}$')

    plt.xlabel('$\phi$')
    plt.ylabel('$r(\phi)$')
    plt.legend(loc='best')


    axes = plt.gca()
    axes.set_xlim([-np.pi, np.pi])
    axes.set_ylim([0, 5])
    plt.show()

arc()
```

[image]

I don't understand why it doesn't go all the way to the `\phi` axis on the right side. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Only ask one question per question, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to get what you want is to use [linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html). To get a vector `x` that is almost the same as in your example, you should do

```
x = np.linspace(-np.pi/4, np.pi/4, round(np.pi / 2 / 0.001) + 1)
```

or simply

```
x = np.linspace(-np.pi/4, np.pi/4, npoints)
```

This gives you **exactly** `npoints` points, and the start and stop values are guaranteed to be included.

Using `np.arange(start, stop, step)` gives you the points `start, start+step, start+2*step, ...` until the final point for which `start+n*step < stop`. Due to floating point inaccuracies, it is not obvious what is the `n` of the final point. The [manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) of `arange` remarks:

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not
>   be consistent. It is better to use linspace for these cases.

It is easy to demonstrate that this leads to unpredictable behavior by generating some aranges between 0 and 1 with variable step size:

```
In [21]: for i in range(97,109):
    ...:     r = np.arange(0, 1, 1. / i)
    ...:     print 'step = 1.0 / {}, length = {}, last value = {}'.format(
    ...:         i, len(r), r[-1])
    ...:     
step = 1.0 / 97, length = 97, last value = 0.989690721649
step = 1.0 / 98, length = 99, last value = 1.0
step = 1.0 / 99, length = 99, last value = 0.989898989899
step = 1.0 / 100, length = 100, last value = 0.99
step = 1.0 / 101, length = 101, last value = 0.990099009901
step = 1.0 / 102, length = 102, last value = 0.990196078431
step = 1.0 / 103, length = 104, last value = 1.0
step = 1.0 / 104, length = 104, last value = 0.990384615385
step = 1.0 / 105, length = 105, last value = 0.990476190476
step = 1.0 / 106, length = 106, last value = 0.990566037736
step = 1.0 / 107, length = 108, last value = 1.0
step = 1.0 / 108, length = 108, last value = 0.990740740741
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10011517/2647279) to a related question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the graph doesn't go all the way to zero on the right is because `arange` starts at `start` (the first argument) and adds `step` (the third argument) until it reaches `end` (the second argument. **However**, `end` is not added at the end.
What you should do is this:

```
x = np.concatenate((np.arange(-np.pi/4, np.pi/4, 0.001), [np.pi/4]))
```

or use the shorthand `np.r_`:

```
x = np.r_[np.arange(-np.pi/4, np.pi/4, 0.001), np.pi/4]
```

Comment: This solution might work for this particular problem, but it might give unexpected results in the general case. As my example showed, the final value of `arange` can become very close to the stop value, for example `np.arange(0, 1, 1.0/98)[-1] - 1 == -1.11e-16`, so by simply concatenating the final value, the final 2 points would be *very* close.

Answer (score 1):

I changed
`x = np.arange((-np.pi)/4, (np.pi)/4, 0.001)`

to:

`x = np.arange((-np.pi)/4, (np.pi)/4, 0.00001)`

and I got [image: A closer to perfect plot]

Essentially, just change the step to get closer to the end of the curve.
However, this is more of an example of what not to do (my guess turned out to be erroneous).
As @Bas Swinckels' suggestion is even better:

`x = np.linspace(-np.pi/4, np.pi/4, npoints)`

It entirely gets rid of the need to change the last argument to a value closer to zero, which only makes the gap smaller (It doesn't get rid of the gap). The linspace is better for floating point inaccuracies.

Comment: yes, I did think about adding delta x but it didn't help, interestingly your solution works. A mystery. Thank you, though.

Comment: If you zoom in you'll see that there's still a gap. You just made it smaller.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that is why `x = np.arange((-np.pi)/4, (np.pi)/4+0.001, 0.001)` is better. I'll edit for clarity

Comment: No. It's the same problem again. I explained in my answer how arange works.