# Numpy arange function has inconsistent behaviour (potentially bug?)

Tags: python, numpy

I found a very strange behaviour of numpy.arange.

If I wrote

```
np.arange(1.1, 1.7, 0.1)
```

it returns `array([ 1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6])` as expected.

However, when I wrote:

```
np.arange(1.1, 1 + 0.1 * 7, 0.1)
```

it returns `array([ 1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7])`.

Is this a bug or I used it in a wrong way?

Comment: Possible explanation at: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011302/python-numpy-arange-unexpected-results?rq=1

Comment: `0.1` is an infinite number in binary...

Comment: Also related: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @ayhan That's very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Consider `np.arange(11, 17) * 0.1` for predictable behaviour