# Python numpy unexpected results in arange and linspace

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I need to create a square-shaped grid with both `x` and `y` axes having the following parameters:

```
min_range = 0
max_range = 0.8
cell_size = 0.01
```

And what I do:

```
import numpy as np
x_ax = np.arange(min_range, max_range, cell_size) ### This gives [0,...,0.1,...,0.29,0.79]
y_ax = np.arange(min_range, max_range, cell_size) ### This also gives [0,...,0.1,...,0.29,0.79]
### Cartesian product
lattice = np.transpose([np.tile(x_ax, y_ax.shape[0]), np.repeat(y_ax, x_ax.shape[0])])
```

Then, `lattice` matrix is passed as an argument to another function and a value is assigned to each of its cells. I need to visualize this grid with the assigned values stored in a separate array. So what I do is:

```
lattice = np.asarray(lattice/cell_size,dtype=np.int32) ###This is supposed to contain matrix indices.
```

And this is where I get strange results. Some of the values in the `lattice` matrix, for example `0.29` when divided by `0.01` which is the `cell_size` give `28`. I cannot figure out where this problem is coming from as it happens only for a few of the values in the intended range. I suspected it was the rounding issue with the floating point numbers as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011302/python-numpy-arange-unexpected-results) and tried it with `np.linspace` as well. But that did not help either.

How can I make this visualization work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Python console you will see

```
>>> 0.29/0.01
28.999999999999996
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.int32(0.29/0.01)
28
```

So you are on the right path. This is due to floating point calculation. As soon as you cast it to `np.int32`, the decimal places will be truncated and the result is `28`. Instead of just casting, you should round the result:

```
>>> np.int32(np.round(0.29/0.01))
29
```

For your application that means you have to write

```
lattice = np.asarray(np.round(lattice/cell_size),dtype=np.int32) ###This is supposed to contain matrix indices.
```